# Error "Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java" after entering my input. Believe it is hex conversion

Tags: java

So I have been working on this code for homework and I feel like I have gotten most of the bugs worked out but I keep getting the below error when I actually run the program.

Error String:

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java
.lang.String
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatte
r.java:4331)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.
java:2846)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:28
00)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2581)
        at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:974)
        at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:870)
        at ESUnit3Ch12.main(ESUnit3Ch12.java:47)
```

---

I think that it might have something to do with the conversion to Hex but I can't pinpoint the issue. My code is as follows:

Code:

---

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class ESUnit3Ch12
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {


        final String HEADER_FMT_STR = "%-8s%-20s%-20s%-4s\n";
        final String DATA_FMT_STR = "%-8d%,-20d%,-20d%,-4d\n";
        int index1 = 0; // 
        int index2 = 0; // 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\nPlease enter a string of any length: "); // User input that will be converted into ASCII and Hex
        String UserInput = sc.nextLine();



        System.out.printf(HEADER_FMT_STR, "Initial", "ASCII(char)", "ASCII(int)", "Hex");
        for (int i=0; i< UserInput.length(); i++) //
        {
            char ch1 = UserInput.charAt(i); //convet the ch1 @ this index to ASCII
            int ASCII = (int) ch1; //int ASCII <-- store as a variable
            if (Character.isDigit(ch1))
            {
                System.out.printf(DATA_FMT_STR, "", "", ASCII, Integer.toHexString(ASCII));
            } 
            else
            {
                System.out.printf(DATA_FMT_STR, "", ASCII, "", Integer.toHexString(UserInput.charAt(i)));
            }
        }


        System.out.println("\nThank you for playing!");


    } // end main
} // end class
```

---

Any tips or tricks that could resolve the issue are appreciated

Comment: The error message is perfectly clear. You are passing a `String` to a format string which expects `%d`. This means an integer, which `String` is obviously not, so you get an error telling you `java.lang.String` does not match `%d`.

Comment: For future reference: A list of format conversions and flags can be found here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html